# Disable Remote Desktop(from server 2008) to domain users for each other

Tags: windows

situtation is: I have my server running on windows server 2008 R2 version and 20 local users are connected thorugh active directory and i want to stop users(from server) to take rdp for each other's system in that domain. Can I do it and how please tell the complete steps. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: simply make sure they are not in the 'Remote Desktop Users' group on the desktop machines but only on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a Group Policy on the server.

Click Start – All programs – Administrative Tools – Group Policy Management.
Create or Edit Group Policy Objects.
Expand Computer Configuration – Administrative Templates – Windows Components – Remote Desktop Services – Remote Desktop Session Host – Connections.
Allow users to connect remotely using Remote Desktop Services (enable or disable)